# Can i add values from a list to another list within a loop?

Tags: python, list, encryption, indexing

I am trying to add values from a list to other values from a different list. So if i had 40 in a list and 8 in another, i want to be able to do 40 - 8 in terms of the index. The tricky part is i am trying to do it in a loop, each time with a different value.

```py
listOfDigits = [40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120]
listOfValues = [8, 5, 7, 1, 4, 9]
```

I want to be able to take 8 away from 40, then add 5 to 50 then 7 away from 60....up until add 9 to 80 ...inside of a loop. Once i get past last value in "list of values" i want it to start again, by taking 8 away from 100, then add 5 to 110 ... etc and repeat for the values.

Hopefully this makes sense. I am unsure as to how one would go about this problem.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I was attempting to use a for loop, to add each value by their index. So
listOfValues[0] - listOfDigits[0]
I would then add those new values into a list, the tricky part is having the loop as i am unsure how to implement it, due to the fact it has to start again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the perfect opportunity to combine [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), [`cycle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) and [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).

The `cycle()` will ensure your "start again" requirement.
The `zip()` allows you to iterate the two lists at the same time.
The `enumerate()` is used to decide to add or substract the values.

```
from itertools import cycle

digits = listOfDigits
values = cycle(listOfValues)

for i, (digit, value) in enumerate(zip(digits, values)):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        print(digit - value)
    else:
        print(digit + value)
```

Comment: Brilliant, i was looking into enumarate yesterday. Bit more of an insight into what i am doing, i not only have to add and subtract, i also have to times the 3rd number in the array (in this case 7) and then take away that new value from the number like the rest of them. Is there a simpler way to do this just like the code above, as the way you have shown with cycle and enumerate is exactly what i am looking for.

Comment: @DannyTaylor This is probably easy to do, just check for `i % 3` instead of `2`